# Firebase analytics log event issue with List type parameters in the Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to create a custom `logEvent` to monitor the changes in my JSON model using the Firebase dashboard. The following class is an example of my object with a method to create a JSON map:

```dart
class AddressInfo {
  String address;
  String city;
  List<String> phoneNumbers = <String>[];

  AddressInfo({
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.phoneNumbers,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'address': address,
        'city': city,
        'phoneNumbers': phoneNumbers,
      };
}
```

I called the function `logEvent` of [FirebaseAnalytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics), and passed the JSON object in `parameters` like this:

```
_sendAnalyticsEvent(String eventName, AddressInfo addressInfo) async {
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

  await analytics.logEvent(
    name: eventName,
    parameters: addressInfo.toJson(),
  );
}
```

And, I get the below exception in the Flutter console:

```dart
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value type: java.util.ArrayList
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.createBundleFromMap(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:188)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.handleLogEvent(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:118)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:84)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics(19272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
E/flutter (19272): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Unsupported value type: java.util.ArrayList, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value type: java.util.ArrayList
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.createBundleFromMap(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:188)
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.handleLogEvent(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:118)
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java:84)
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (19272):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/flutter (19272):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (19272):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter (19272):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/flutter (19272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
E/flutter (19272):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (19272):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/flutter (19272):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
E/flutter (19272): )
E/flutter (19272): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581:7)
E/flutter (19272): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (19272): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19272): #2      FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent (package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart:43:5)
E/flutter (19272): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I faced a Java error because I'm using an Android device for development. Also, the exception reveals an issue with converting `ArrayList` when passing an object of dart type **List** to the `logEvent` method like the `phoneNumbers` in the `AddressInfo`. The expectation is we should be able to log a list because sometimes our list is growable, and its length is unexpected. So, separating parameters is the last choice and not recommended.

I'm using Flutter `Channel stable, 2.0.2`, and I will also test on an iOS device to see if the problem is specific to Android.

#### Update

It seems there is an open GitHub issue related to this problem here:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2835

### Question

Should I fix this issue by developing a native implementation for each platform? Or am I missing something here with doing custom events?

Comment: can you pass addressinfo as String? Also there is a 40 characters limit for each parameter in logevent. See the documentation https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en

Comment: for now problem still exist